# Remembering destination when logging-in is required in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **Flutter** app with a home page that shows all the products , and a **product details screen** that contains a button that require the user to **log-in** , how to return the user to selected product after he **log-in** Successfully.

Comment: Simply do `Navigator.of(context).pop(result)`   result can tell whether the login was a success or failed

Comment: but some pages need to be refreshed ,HOW to do that

Comment: What does that mean. ? You should provide some code sample or anything else to make us understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that `Navigator.of(context).pop(result)` will navigate to the last page but it will not reload the page i.e. `initState()` of the `State` class will not be called again.

Try using a callback function in the `LoginPage` and call that once the login is successful right before calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()`. Then in the product details page provide a callback handler to the same and in that just call `setState((){})`; this will force your page to reload only if the login was successful. A sample code below:

**Login Page:**

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback onLoginSuccess;

  const LoginPage ({this.onLoginSuccess});

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}    

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  ...

  _onLogin(){
    bool status = true; // do actual login
    if(status){
      widget.onLoginSuccess();
    }
  } 
}
```

**Product Details Page:**

```
class ProductDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductDetailsPageState createState() => _ProductDetailsPageState();
}    

class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {
  ...

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
    final loginPage = LoginPage(
      onLoginSuccess: () => setState((){}); // Empty setState to force rebuild page
    );

    // Navigate to login page using loginPage based on your requirement
  }
}
```